# Javascript sounds and effects on buttons not working on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having trouble with javascript executing in html.  To my knowledge the links and code is spelled correctly but I cant get the sound to play. No errors listed when I inspect the page and event listeners are listed but wont play sound. The last 4 are crossed out on purpose until i put in correct sounds.  Here is my code...

```js
var numberofAnimals = document.querySelectorAll(".animal").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberofAnimals; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".animal")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;

    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);

    buttonAnimation(buttonInnerHTML);

  });
}



document.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){

  makeSound(event.key);

  buttonAnimation(event.key);

});

function makeSound(key) {

  switch (key) {
    case "lion":
      var lion = new Audio("sounds/lion.mp3");
      lion.play();
      break;

    case "eagle":
      var eagle = new Audio("sounds/eagle.mp3");
      eagle.play();
      break;

    case "wolf":
      var wolf = new Audio("sounds/wolf.mp3");
      wolf.play();
      break;

    case "chicken":
      var chicken = new Audio("sounds/chicken.mp3");
      chicken.play();
      break;

    // case "cheetah":
    //   var cheetah = new Audio("sounds/cheetah.mp3");
    //   cheetah.play();
    //   break;
    //
    // case "mockingbird":
    //   var mockingbird = new Audio("sounds/mockingbird.mp3");
    //   mockingbird.play();
    //   break;
    //
    // case "giraffe":
    //   var giraffe = new Audio("sounds/giraffe.mp3");
    //   giraffe.play();
    //   break;
    //
    // case "elephant":
    //   var elephant = new Audio("sounds/elephant.mp3");
    //   elephant.play();
    //   break;

    default: console.log(key);
  }
}

function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {

  var activeButton = document.querySelector("." + currentKey);

  activeButton.classList.add("pressed");

  setTimeout(function() {
    activeButton.classList.remove("pressed");
  }, 100);

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFF8E8;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Rubik Moonrocks', cursive;
  color: #202030;
}

.lion {
  background-image:url('../images/lion.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.eagle {
  background-image:url('../images/eagle.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wolf {
  background-image:url('../images/wolf.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.chicken {
  background-image:url('../images/chicken.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cheetah {
  background-image:url('../images/cheetah.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mockingbird {
  background-image:url('../images/mockingbird.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.giraffe {
  background-image:url('../images/giraffe.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.elephant {
  background-image:url('../images/elephant.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.animal {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.animal:hover {
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Click Safari</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Lobster&family=Rubik+Moonrocks&family=Smooch&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Click Safari</h1>
    <h3>Click each animal to hear what they sound like</h3>
    <h3>Enjoy!</h3>

    <div class="set set1">
      <button class="animal lion">Lion</button>
      <button class="animal eagle">Eagle</button>
      <button class="animal wolf">Wolf</button>
      <button class="animal chicken">Chicken</button>
    </div>

    <div class="set set2">
      <button class="animal cheetah">Cheetah</button>
      <button class="animal mockingbird">Mockingbird</button>
      <button class="animal giraffe">Giraffe</button>
      <button class="animal elephant">Elephant</button>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to hear the animals. Where is this hosted?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting into trouble with the `innerHTML` lookup of the elements.  You are passing in `Lion` but the switch statement is expecting `lion`.  This will never evaluate to the `audio.play` cases.

Suggested solution would be to call `toLowerCase()` on the `innerHTML` strings so that they will match.  Currently with your stack snippet the `querySelector` isn't returning any elements because of this.

```
var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thank You! That seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Cool, don't forget to like, comment, and subscribe